# After installed asprise_ocr_sdk_python_api on mac, got "No module named 'ocr'"

Tags: python, ocr, barcode, asprise-ocr-api

I ran both

```
sudo pip install asprise_ocr_sdk_python_api

pip install asprise_ocr_sdk_python_api
```

Got message

```
"Requirement already satisfied: asprise_ocr_sdk_python_api in /Users/myid/miniconda3/envs/competition/lib/python3.5/site-packages"
```

But when I ran asprise_ocr to test:

Got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myuser/miniconda3/envs/competition/bin/asprise_ocr", line 7, in <module>
    from asprise_ocr_api.ocr_app import run_ocr_app
  File "/Users/myuser/miniconda3/envs/competition/lib/python3.5/site-packages/asprise_ocr_api/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ocr import *
ImportError: No module named 'ocr'
```

Answer (score 0):

The asprise_ocr_api module doesn't do submodule imports correctly in Python 3.
For example **init**.py contains from ocr import *. For a sub-module in Python 3 that should be from .ocr import *. Idem for from ocr_app import OcrApp, run_ocr_app. That should be from .ocr_app import OcrApp, run_ocr_app.
After making these changes in all files it imports correctly.

Answer (score 0):

i've tried:

> import ocr

same error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ocr'

i am using python 3